# Ace Editor - Change CTRL+H keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, ace-editor

I'm working on an implementation of *Ace Editor* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works great for the built-in "Find" dialog, however I'm trying to find a way to change out the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and prevent default behavior.

I've looked over docs and forums about working with the keybindings but I can't identify what method is being called to instantiate the 'replace' dialog or how to overwrite it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace command is defined [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/commands/default_commands.js#L366). it is possible to use the following code to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "replace",
    bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-R", mac: "Command-Option-F"},
    exec: function(editor) {
        require("ace/config").loadModule("ace/ext/searchbox", function(e) {
             e.Search(editor, true)  
             // take care of keybinding inside searchbox           
             // this is too hacky :(             
             var kb = editor.searchBox.$searchBarKb
             command = kb.commandKeyBinding["ctrl-h"]
             if (command && command.bindKey.indexOf("Ctrl-R") == -1) {
                 command.bindKey += "|Ctrl-R"
                 kb.addCommand(command)
             }
         });
    }
});
```

but the part with inner command is quite ugly, i'd suggest to make an issue on ace repository to either use normal name for it, or pick up `replace` commands key automatically

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
name: 'replace',
bindKey: {win: 'Ctrl-R', mac: 'Command-Option-F'},
exec: function(editor) {
ace.config.loadModule("ace/ext/searchbox", function(e) {e.Search(editor, true)});
},
readOnly: true
});
```