# ace editor - simply re-enable command after disabled it

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to simply re-enable a command after I disabled it...
This is how I simply disabled it:

```
editor.commands.removeCommand("backspace");
```

But now I need to enable it again but I don't know how to do it...

I found something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633324/ace-editor-change-ctrlh-keybinding) but it is very difficult..

Is there a way to simple re-enable it?

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the command to add it back later

```
var command = editor.commands.byName.backspace
editor.commands.removeCommand(command)
editor.commands.addCommand(command)
```

or to remove only the key

```
function setCommandEnabled(editor, name, enabled) {
    var command = editor.commands.byName[name]
    if (!command.bindKeyOriginal) 
        command.bindKeyOriginal = command.bindKey
    command.bindKey = enabled ? command.bindKeyOriginal : null;
    editor.commands.addCommand(command);
    // special case for backspace and delete which will be called from
    // textarea if not handled by main commandb binding
    if (!enabled) {
        var key = command.bindKeyOriginal;
        if (key && typeof key == "object")
            key = key[editor.commands.platform];
        if (/backspace|delete/i.test(key))
            editor.commands.bindKey(key, "null")
    }
}
```

and then call

```
setCommandEnabled(editor, "backspace", false)
setCommandEnabled(editor, "backspace", true)
```