# Reset Key Bindings - Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

OK, I'm doing a few experiments with [Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/) and I'm trying to control what keys/shortcuts have been bound.

The best way I could think of would be to totally eliminate/reset all keybinding, and re-set only the ones I need.

How is that doable?

Any ideas?

---

**P.S.** I've had a look into the the whole documentation (and the list of ["default" Key Bindings](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts)) but I'm still not sure. I've also played with the JS console and `editor.keyBinding.getKeyboardHandler()` but I still cannot find any suitable way/method/property to unset a specific keybinding.

---

Trying this approach ([Ace Editor - Change CTRL+H keybinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633324/ace-editor-change-ctrlh-keybinding)), I tried `editor.commands.findnext={}` in order - for instance - to eliminate the Cmd+G binding to the "Find Next" command. However, the shortcut is still there... :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all commands do

```
var allCommands = editor.commands.byName; 
editor.commands.removeCommands(allCommands)
// now you can add commands as you wish
allCommands.findnext.bindKey = {win: "Ctrl-H", mac: "Cmd-H"}
editor.commands.addCommand(allCommands.findnext)
```

But if you want to only remove particular binding, call

```
editor.commands.bindKey("Cmd-G", null)
```

Comment: One word: awesome. You made my day! :-)

Comment: thanks, i have updated the answer to make it less confusing

Comment: I get "bindkey is not a function" :-(